# python running in crontab delivers empty mail

Tags: python, selenium

I am running a crontab job on MacOS Catalina. This crontab job runs multiple python scrips for which each job is sending an email. Only the last python script is using Selenium and the job sends an empty email.

The cronjob for this last python script is as follows

```
58 6 * * * export DISPLAY=:0  &&  cd ~/Documents/Python/cron && /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 wta.py 2>&1$ | mail -s "Report" a@b.c
```

The Python code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import mysql.connector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s=Service("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
chrome_driver='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.wtatennis.com/rankings/singles')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')

....

val2=[updatetime,'WTA']
query2="""UPDATE Update_date SET Updated = %s WHERE Tablename = %s"""
mycursor.execute(query2,val2)
db.commit()
print(val2)

....
```

When I run this code in Atom (without the first line) it works perfectly.
I searched stackoverflow and other sources but did not find a workable solution.

Comment: odd that you arent getting any errors. could you add a print early in your code and see if at least that arrives in the email?

Comment: first you could use `logging` or normal file to safe some information about values in variables, etc. when it runs in cron.  You could also put code in `try/except` to catch errors and save in `logging`. In `cron` code may run with different privileges, in different `current working directory` (`os.getcwd()`), it may not have access to DISPLAY, etc. and all this can make problem.

Comment: @Nullman - I added a print just after calling the selenium.webdriver. The result is still an empty email

Comment: @furas. When I send it to a file instead of mail the python script works without errors. Very strange, since my cron jobs sent a correct mail

Comment: Here is what is working now: 59 6 * * * cd ~/Documents/Python/cron && /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 atp.py 2>&1 | mail -s "ATP Report" a@b.c
*/1 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0  &&  cd ~/Documents/Python/cron && /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 wta.py 2>&1 >>  ~/Documents/Python/cron/backup.log
For ATP I receive now a correct mail (but does not contain Selenium). For wta I now get a correct log file, but when I email the mail is empty and the python script did not run

Comment: do you runs it in background ? maybe this is problem - it may not display it in current process.

Comment: BTW: I don't see any `print()` in code - if you don't use `print()` then it can't display it and it can't send it to files/mails

Comment: @furas Yes I use print in the mails, that's why in the other one I get data. I know that is not running in the background, since I let the last update timestamp updated in the script in a database

Comment: you should use `print()` in this code to send information to `mail`. And you could use `print()` to debug code - to see which line is executed and what you have in variables when it runs in cron.

Comment: @furas: I added some lines of the script so you can see that I do print(). This part of the code is always hit.

Comment: What's that dollar sign doing in `2>&1$` ?

Comment: Added the mail message

Comment: Message 1:
From t@iMac-van-Gebruiker.local  Mon May  2 14:04:13 2022
X-Original-To: t
Delivered-To: t@iMac-van-Gebruiker.local
From: t@iMac-van-Gebruiker.local (Cron Daemon)
To: t@iMac-van-Gebruiker.local
Subject: Cron <t@iMac-van-Gebruiker> export DISPLAY=:0  &&  cd ~/Documents/Python/cron && /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 wta.py 2>&1  >>  ~/Documents/Python/cron/backup.log | mail -s "WTA" a@b.c 
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=t>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=t>
Date: Mon,  2 May 2022 14:04:13 +0200 (CEST)
Null message body; hope that's ok

Comment: Notice that the subject of this mail is "Cron...", which means that this is the mail that cron sends automatically, not the result of your mail command (where you have a -s flag to set subject to something else). Also, the command shown in the subject of this mail is not the same as what you show in the question!